# Why isn't the ball used in football called "a football ball"?

Tags: word-usage

We know that you need a ball to play cricket, golf, or tennis, and we refer to the balls used in those sports as "cricket ball", "golf ball" and "tennis ball" respectively: you take the name of the sport and then add the word "ball".

But as "football" is the name of the sport itself, why isn't a football referred to as a "football ball"? The same applies to "netball ball", "basketball ball" and "volleyball ball" of course.

Comment: IMO Because they already have *ball* at end. The same thing is observed in grammar too. Like, the plural of grass can't be called grass*s* because grass already has *s* at its last, instead *es* is used to pluralify the word whose end are already *s*.

Comment: People don't like to repeat themselves?

Comment: Because football is the world's most extensive sport, and nothing else comes within a thousand miles of its popularity? No need, everyone knows what a football is.

Comment: Do you call it a "baseball ball"?

Comment: @WS2 - If "everyone knows", why do they know two different things?

Answer (score 9):

Your question implies that *football* properly describes the game and, by extension, the ball itself. I wasn't sure, so I checked and it is indeed the case historically. [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=football) says:

> **football**
>   open-air game, first recorded c. 1400. Forbidden in a Scottish statute of 1424. The first reference to the ball itself is late 15th century.

So, usage of the term to refer to the ball instead of the game is quite old, but it still took more than a century after the name of the game was established. Nothing is said of the reasons we don't say “football ball”, so I assume that it was the obvious: to avoid unwarranted repetition.

Comment: +1 for: "I assume that it was the obvious: to avoid unwarranted repetition."

Comment: I was about to answer that it's -obvious- that the games are named after the ball, but inspection shows that is not universal. 'Golfball', (american) 'soccer ball', 'ping pong ball'. First comes the name of the game, then the name of the ball. And repeating 'ball' is just ludicrous.

Comment: @Mitch: It's not *that* "ludicrous". There are hundreds of instances of ["a baseball ball"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a+baseball+ball%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) and ["a football ball"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a+football+ball%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google Books, and I bet there will be many thousands more on the Internet at large.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Ludicrous != nonexistent. Those are all silly.

Answer (score 7):

I think we don't say ball twice because it would be redundant to do so.

The name of the game lets you know that you are playing a ballgame, a pastime that requires one to put a ball in motion.

So we just name the ball with the game name to show that a specialized ball appropriate for that game is needed to play it.

Answer (score 1):

We usually add the name of the sport before 'ball' because most sports don't have a special name for the ball. But some sports do have special ball names:

The ball in badminton is known as a 'shuttlecock'.
The ball in football is known as a 'football'.
The ball in netball is known as a 'netball'.

Comment: Doesn't this beg the question?

Comment: No, the OP wondered why we say "a football" instead of "a football ball". As I pointed out, it's for the same reason we say "a shuttlecock" instead of "a badminton ball"—because these sports have a special name for the ball.

Comment: But the football = ball usage arose after the football = game. What was the earlier 'special name' or 'not so special name'?  // There are 'special names' for the balls used in cricket, rounders, snooker .... The reason we don't use 'football ball' say **as** the 'special name' is almost certainly because 'football ball' sounds distinctly odd and has done to many generations.

Comment: I don't think the OP was asking about etymology of 'footballs' and 'baseballs'. He was asking why footballs are treated gramatically differently to other sports balls. Why not use the same word construction for all balls? I was pointing out that some balls have a special name—a fact that isn't immediately obvious until you consider the example of shuttlecocks.

Answer (score 0):

In reading the question, I realized that in basketball, football (American and English), volleyball, the ball is virtually the only equipment (ignoring safety equipment) that is used. Whereas in golf, tennis, cricket there is always another critical component, i.e., club, racket, bat.

(An exception to this would be the game of baseball.)

Comment: And then there’s hockey, a game played with sticks and a puck. The word *puck* in northern countries pretty much automatically means *hockey puck*.  Elsewhere you would probably need both words.